# Install AutoMod phpBB

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I would like to enable mods installation in my forum. Therefore, I first have to install `AutoMod`.

Installing AutoMod requires uploading of some folders to the server. These files have names as existing files on the server, and in case of uploading may override them.

Is there a way to avoid overwriting of my forum folder?

Comment: Your best bet is to install MODs manually, I never did trust AutoMod

Comment: @Eeji, Well, how to do it manually? and why do you suspect the AutoMod?

Comment: Download the mod and open `install.xml` in your browser for full installation instructions. I'm just very wary of anything that automatically changes code, especially if there are other mods installed.